# Model validation does not work in rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation, model

Why does this model validator

`validates_format_of :weight, :with => /\A\d{1,3}\.\d{0,2}\Z/, :on => :create`

matches on

```
12.4kg
```

though it sould not

EDIT:
the view form

```
<%= form_for :new_client do |f| %>
<% if @new_client.errors.any? %>
    <div class="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@new_client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited data from being send:</h2>
        <ul>
            <% @new_client.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
                <li><%= msg %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :weight %>          <%= f.text_field :weight %><br/>
    <%= f.label :height %>          <%= f.text_field :height %><br/>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

i check for all errors, i think, but the point is, that the weight should not be valid and should produce an error, but it doesn't.

Comment: The regexp looks fine, and the string does not match on rubular: http://rubular.com/r/p6Dfw98Pjo ... could you post the code where you create and save your model ?

Comment: please delete the comment and edit your post instead!

Answer (score 0):

A common error is to forget to display the error messages, especially if you display the same form after saving the form. This error already cost me hours of debugging. Do you check `@model.errors` in your view?

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem.
in my migration file the weight column was a float instead of a string.